# How to use Math.round to round numbers to the nearest EVEN number?

Tags: javascript, rounding

Using JavaScript only please.

This is the first time I am attempting to write JavaScript on my own. I've successfully manipulated codes that friends have written for me in the past, but I have never written my own from scratch, nor took the time to try and understand the language itself until recently.

I'm trying to make a basic bra size calculator that takes numbers (measurements) from user input, routes them into a function and returns (calculates) a bra size to the user.

Since I'm so new to this language, I'm only trying to write one part right now - "band size"

I have an input field for users to type in their "under bust measurement" which I currently have set to round. This works as it intended. See here

```
<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

 function calculate() 
  {
   var underbust = document.getElementById("underBust").value;

    if (underbust.length === 0) 
     {
      alert("Please enter your underbust measurement in inches");
      return;
     }

    document.getElementById("bandsize").innerHTML = Math.round(underbust);
   }

</script>

</head>

<body>
<input type="number" id="underBust" /> inches<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="calculate()" /><br>
<b>underbust:</b> <div id="bandsize">bandsize will appear here</div><br>
</body>

</html>
```

However, I don't need the input 'underBust' to round to the nearest whole number. I need it to round to the nearest EVEN whole number, since bra band sizes only come in even whole numbers.

For example, if the user inputs the number "31.25" the code would currently round it to "31" but I need it to round it to "32"

If the user inputs the number "30.25" the code would round it correctly to "30" because the nearest whole number and nearest whole even number are the same in this case. However, if the user inputs "30.5" the code would round it up to "31" but I still need it to round down to "30"

Basically, I need the number to be rounded UP if the user input is equal to or greater than an odd number (29.00 becomes 30, 31.25 becomes 32, etc.). If the user input is greater than or equal to an even number and less than the next odd number (28, 28.25, 28.75, etc.) I need it to round down (in the previous example, to 28 for all cases). The odd number is the middle divide for rounding, instead of the ".5" of any number.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

This should do it:

```
2 * Math.round(underbust / 2);
```

Comment: Thank you! I feel like this is some basic math that I should know but wasn't considering...

yep. Just did the math and I feel stupid now.

Comment: I could give you a mathematical explanation but probably you can understand it better by computing the expression with your example values in your head.

Comment: Nearest ODD is then: 2* Math.floor(n/2) + 1

Comment: In case of decimals, you could use Math.ceil() to round off to highest even integer.

Comment: @Nitin No, `Math.ceil(0.1)` rounds to 1 (odd), not 0 (even)

Comment: @Henrik, I think Nitin was referring to Math.ceil() as in `2 * Math.ceil(0.1 / 2)` which would give 2 - the next even integer.

Comment: This doesn't produce what I would expect for negative odd integers: `2 * Math.round(-1 / 2) === 0` but I would expect `-2`. `Math.round` rounds towards `+Infinity`. 

Answer (score 1):

If you also wish to format, building on @Bergi's answer:

```
function roundToEven(value) {
  return Number.isNaN(n)
    ? 0.0
    : 2 * Math.round(value / 2);
}

/**
 * Round-to-even with a fixed number of decimals (2 decimals = to cent/öre). Returns [ rounded value, formatted rounded value ].
 * @param {*} n The number to round-to-even, with the given number of decimals
 * @param {*} decimals The number of decimals in base10 to round the number at.
 */
function roundToEvenFixed(n, decimals = 2.0) {
  if (Number.isNaN(n) || Number.isNaN(decimals)) {
    return 0.0
  }

  const value = (Math.round((n * Math.pow(10, decimals)) / 2) * 2) / Math.pow(10, decimals),
        formatted = value.toFixed(decimals);

  return [ value, formatted ]
}
```

Very useful when you want un-biased rounding. Usage:

```
console.log(`Amount: ${roundToEvenFixed(i.quantity * i.unitPrice.amount)[1]} kr`)
```

#### Refs

- [Math.round](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)
- [Number.toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)
- [Math.pow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow)
- [Number.isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN)

Comment: This answer is correct based on the question, but if you're looking for a "round to nearest even if the distance is equal" answer (like used in some scientific situations) there is still an issue with this answer. It is getting closer, but try `roundToEvenFixed(0.12510, 2)`. This rounds to 0.12, while it should round to 0.13 since it is closer to 0.13 than 0.12. I haven't found a way to solve that yet.

Comment: @DolfAndringa I just wrote this:

https://gist.github.com/eeeps/75a31a2e1815b8bd4bf621de890f47e4

Which rounds to integers using the strategy you describe. To round to a fixed number of decimals you could then `roundToEvenIfEquidistant( n * 100 ) / 100`.

Answer (score -2):

I am an absolute amateur, but I made in a wrong way

2 * parseInt(value/2)

But it did exactly what I needed - Math.round rounds it by 0,5
ParseInt did it at 0

Comment: This is wrong, because `2*parseInt(1.5/2) = 0`, but should be `2`

Comment: `parseInt` is meant to find an integer at the start of a string; never use it for operations on numbers. For instance, `parseInt(0.0000001)` gives `1`  because `0.0000001.toString()` is `"1e-7"` and `parseInt("1e-7")` stops when it encounters the `e`.