# How to round "p.value" js to the closest even number

Tags: rounding, calculator

In my website there is a simple calculator, which divide 6000 on a certain number

```
<form oninput="p.value = 6000 / parseFloat(rpms.value)">
<input type="number" id="rpms" >
<input type="number" id="p" name="Number" disabled>
```

Please help me to round the **p.value** of the second input field to the closest even number.

I want it to be integer, without any decimal places

Thank you in advance!

I did several searches, but ... I am absolute amateur with JS and had no idea where and how to put it in the html code.

However I managed to do it like this:
oninput="p.value = parseInt(6000 / parseFloat(rpms.value))"

But then I remembered that only EVEN numbers are allowed in this formula, which calculates the number of poles of induction motors.

So, please help me do it rounding to the closest even number.

Comment: Use Math.round(number);

Comment: a simple search would show you at least 100 ways to to that!?

Comment: I did several searches, but ... I am absolute amateur with JS and had no idea where and how to put it in the html code.

However I managed to do it like this:
oninput="p.value = parseInt(6000 / parseFloat(rpms.value))"

But then I remembered that only EVEN numbers are allowed in this formula, which calculates the number of poles of induction motors.

So, please help me do it rounding to the closest even number.

Comment: Take a look on this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round

Comment: You could take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442831/how-to-use-math-round-to-round-numbers-to-the-nearest-even-number

Comment: @Saroj - sorry, but he want to round value to the closest even number.

Comment: @teo. Gud That I didn't noticed. Well you gave the exact solution.

Comment: I am an absolute amateur, but I made in a wrong way

p.value = 2*parseInt(6000 / parseFloat(rpms.value)/2)

But it did exactly what I needed
In the example which teo gave -
Math.round rounds it by 0,5
ParseInt did it at 0

Comment: @BochoTodorov 's answer is wrong; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442831/how-to-use-math-round-to-round-numbers-to-the-nearest-even-number

Answer (score 1):

Here's how:

```
function roundToEven(value) {
  return Number.isNaN(n)
    ? 0.0
    : 2 * Math.round(value / 2);
}

/**
 * Round-to-even with a fixed number of decimals (2 decimals = to cent/öre). Returns [ rounded value, formatted rounded value ].
 * @param {*} n The number to round-to-even, with the given number of decimals
 * @param {*} decimals The number of decimals in base10 to round the number at.
 */
function roundToEvenFixed(n, decimals = 2.0) {
  if (Number.isNaN(n) || Number.isNaN(decimals)) {
    return 0.0
  }

  const value = (Math.round((n * Math.pow(10, decimals)) / 2) * 2) / Math.pow(10, decimals),
        formatted = value.toFixed(decimals);

  return [ value, formatted ]
}
```

Very useful when you want un-biased rounding. Usage:

```
console.log(`Amount: ${roundToEvenFixed(i.quantity * i.unitPrice.amount)[1]} kr`)
```

#### Refs

- [Math.round](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)
- [Number.toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)
- [Math.pow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow)
- [Number.isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN)

Answer (score -1):

Javascript is providing the [`Math.round(x)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) for the task.

```
p.value = Math.round(6000 / parseFloat(rpms.value));
```

Other Examples

```
Math.round(170.68); // return 171
Math.round(171.32); // return 171
```

Comment: Sorry, but he want to round value to the closest even number.

Comment: @teo Thank you for your notice.

Comment: This is wrong; the question asks for *rounding to the closest even number*.